# Switch K-menu widget to "Application Menu" by script

Tags: bash, kubuntu, kde

The first thing I do after installing Kubuntu is to manually switch from the default K-Menu appearance to the "Application Menu" appearance.

I have two question:

1. How can I do this using a bash script?
2. Can I do that for all user (possibly even future users)?